# JavaScript image replace

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I'm wondering if there's an easy way for a script to loop through all images (possibly of a certain class) on my web page and change the sources of all these images to the same image. This is for an easter egg, and I'd like to avoid AJAX and libraries like jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach((img) => img.src = "someimage.png");
```

```html
<img src="broken1">
<img src="broken2">
<img src="broken3">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) to get all `<img>` elements, like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0, l=imgs.length; i<l; i++) {
  imgs[i].src = "someImage.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Voted for you because of `var i=0, l=imgs.length`, didn't know that that works.

Comment: @thejh - yup, declare as many as you want...`.length` can be expensive to check...or at least adds up since it's checked *every* loop, so best to take that out off the equation :)

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, and that's a pretty cool trick.

Comment: hm? `collection.length` is not expensive at all

Comment: @user205376 - sure it is especially in IE, test it yourself, you'll see the method above (accessing `.length` once) is consistently faster: http://jsperf.com/length-comparison

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++ ) 
  if ( document.images[i].className == 'certain-class' ) // caution: can have multiple classes 
    document.images[i].src = '/hello.jpg';
```

[document.images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.images) is DOM2 adoption from prehistoric DOM0