# Replace all images with one image Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to replace all  tags through a bookmarklet. I am ONLY using javascript. I've tried using the methods used in  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298098/javascript-image-replace) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0, l=imgs.length; i<l; i++) {
imgs[i].src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KL7d7LdSANg/Tm5VLQf9k4I/AAAAAAAAACo/cSV52JoD7vk/s1600/cat-wallpaper-34-713472.jpg";
}
</script>
```

Is the code I was trying out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code is working fine. Maybe there is a problem in another part of your code. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SAVN5/

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not very descriptive. What are you seeing vs what do you expect to see?

Comment: how are you turning this into a bookmarklet?  bookmarklets don't usually have `<script>` in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the "bookmarklet" version of your script

```
javascript:var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(var i=0, l=imgs.length;i<l;i++){imgs[i].src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KL7d7LdSANg/Tm5VLQf9k4I/AAAAAAAAACo/cSV52JoD7vk/s1600/cat-wallpaper-34-713472.jpg";}
```

Comment: How can I apply .style.backgroundImage to this?

Comment: @user2879652 are you serious? See where it says `.src`? That can be whatever property you want to change, in your case `.style.backgroundImage`.

Answer (score -2):

Hold this code in function and call it after DOM is load. Maybe its help u.

Comment: _"I am trying...through a bookmarklet"_

Comment: Oh,sorry,man! Didn't see